# Account and downloading help

Tags: xbox-one

I sold my xbox one to my friend in order to get a new one. I deleted my account off of the old xbox and added it to my new one but when I buy things he also gets them.

Why is this?

Also when downloading, his always downloads before mine and mine goes slow.

Will this affect my speed on downloading things? How can I make it so that he won't receive my purchases?

Answer (score 2):

You deleted your account off the xbox, but did you change which xbox is your "Home Xbox"? On your "Home Xbox" any account can play games you own. The downloading is probably just the relative strengths of your internets and not actually related to the Home versus other Xbox.

Comment: If your friend can access the same games as you, this might be beneficial for multiplayer games where yoi buy the game, and he doesnt own it himself, but you want to play online together